# How to change the order of showing tkinter widgets and running functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a **basic Morse code translator**. I want it to start by showing a window that give you the options of different modes. I want to be able to choose the **translate mode**, then change the window to the "translate screen" and then it should run the translate function .

Instead when I choose my mode it runs the function and then once the function has been completed it changes to the **"translate screen"**

I have tried changing the order in which things run but it didn't do anything. I have no clue what to do. Also I haven't been using tkinter very long.

This is the function to change the window and run the functions once the mode has been selected

```
def choose(selected):
    allOff()#this turns off led
    if selected.get() == 1:
        print("1")
        root.title("Translate")
        trans.grid(column=2, row=0)#shows a label
        backButton.grid(column=2, row=5)# shows a button
        againBtn.grid(column=2, row=4)#shows another button
        clear() #this is to clear the widgets from the choosing screen
        transColorOn() #this just turns on an led
        translate()    #this is the translate function
```

This is the translate function

```
def translate():
    global i, LetterToSend
    inBruh()
    i = 0
    while i < len(morse):
        if LetterToSend == morse[i]:
            print("" + (alphabet[i]))
            letterBig = alphabet[1]
            break
        i += 1
    
    LetterToSend = ""
```

This is the input function

```
def inBruh():
    global LetterToSend
    LetterToSend = ""
    tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
    while tempIN != "done":
        if tempIN == ".":
            LetterToSend = "" + LetterToSend + "."
            print("" + (LetterToSend))
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
        elif tempIN == "-":
            LetterToSend = "" + LetterToSend + "-"
            print("" + (LetterToSend))
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
        else:
            print("plsss valid input\n")
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
```

send help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of information in your question, I have modified the code a little for it to work

```
from tkinter import *

def translate():
    global i, LetterToSend
    inBruh()
    '''i = 0
    while i < len(morse):
        if LetterToSend == morse[i]:
            print("" + (alphabet[i]))
            letterBig = alphabet[1]
            break
        i += 1
    
    LetterToSend = ""'''
    print('Executed translate')

def inBruh():
    global LetterToSend
    LetterToSend = ""
    #tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
    '''while tempIN != "done":
        if tempIN == ".":
            LetterToSend = "" + LetterToSend + "."
            print("" + (LetterToSend))
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
        elif tempIN == "-":
            LetterToSend = "" + LetterToSend + "-"
            print("" + (LetterToSend))
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")
        else:
            print("plsss valid input\n")
            tempIN = input(". or - , then done\n")'''
    print('Executed inBruh')

def choose(selected):
    global root,base_frame

    def clear():
        base_frame.pack_forget()
        print('Cleared main')

    #allOff()#this turns off led
    print('LED: RED')
    if selected.get() == 1:
        print("1")
        root.title("Translate")
        clear() #this is to clear the widgets from the choosing screen
        #trans.grid(column=2, row=0)#shows a label
        #backButton.grid(column=2, row=5)# shows a button
        #againBtn.grid(column=2, row=4)#shows another button
        trans=Label(root,text='Random Label').pack()
        backButton=Button(root,text="Back").pack()
        againBtn=Button(root,text='Again').pack()
        #transColorOn() #this just turns on an led
        print('Turned on an LED')
        translate()    #this is the translate function 

root=Tk()
base_frame=Frame(root)
base_frame.pack(fill='both')
lable=Label(base_frame,text='Hello World').pack()
selected=IntVar()
entry=Entry(base_frame, textvariable=selected)
entry.pack(padx=50)
sub_button=Button(base_frame,text='Submit',command=lambda:choose(selected))
sub_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I have used a frame to have the initial set of widgets and later called `frame.pack_forget()` which removes the frame and its child widgets temporarily and then packed the new set of widgets on the root (you may do it on another frame as well), wherever you need the initial screen back, you can call `frame.pack()`. You can use it with any geometry manager in the same way. Let me know is this was your question or have I interpreted it wrong.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering , I ran the code the underlying issue still seems to be the same . I think it still runs the code before it switches the screen . If you want the full code I can post it here . Thanks anyway : )

Comment: Oh I see, this is the output from my code `LED: RED
1
Cleared main
Turned on an LED
Executed inBruh
Executed translate` I think it clears before running the code.

Comment: It could be possible that your actual function might be time consuming and as it is on the same thread as  the main program, it freezes your main program until its completed, you might want to try multi threading in that case.